# On a local application that stores one set of user credentials, is password salting necessary? Why/Why not?

Tags: security, cryptography, passwords, salt

I've heard a unique salt only provides protection in the event that you have a lot of user credentials stored in the same location. Is there any benefit to salting on a single user application where the password is never sent to the web? Thanks!

Comment: Hashing passwords is usually something you do on servers. Could you explain in more detail what you want to do please?

Comment: I'm trying to build a system with client side encryption, zero knowledge of the password on the server that the user syncs their encrypted data to. Kind of like SpiderOak.

Comment: If the password is only used to encrypt the content client side, why do you need to store the password at all? Wouldn't it be enough to decrypt the content to find out whether the password was correct?

Comment: Newly generated content would need to be encrypted too before transfer, so I need to store the password, or equivalent. Otherwise I would definitely consider your solution. Storing passwords is always a good thing to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Password hashing is used if you don't need to retrieve the original password. For example a website with a account system will hash your password when you register and save the hash of the password in a database. When you login the next time it will again hash the password you entered and compare it to the hash stored in the database. You can use salting to make it even harder to retrieve the original password.

You have a different use case. You want to retrieve the password to be able to decrypt the data that you recieve from the server. To achieve that you have a view options:

1. Generate a key for the user and store it in plaintext on the disk.
2. Don't store the password at all but let the user enter it each time he wants to access the data on the server or upload data to the server (potentially store it in memory, you should make sure to completely erease it from memory bevore the program ends).
3. Generate a key for the user and store on the disk like in option 1 but encrypt it with a password thats handled like the password from option 2.

The 3rd option is definitely the safest of them. You have control over the key generation so you can make sure the key has a decent size to make it impossible for the server to guess while the key is encrypted on the disk.